# How to add page scroll on Adobe Xd?

Tags: adobe-xd, prototyping

I have recently started getting to grips with Adobe Xd, which seems great. I am creating a mobile app prototype and I am stuck with one problem.

It might be a very basic question but how do you enable page scroll on a screen?

Comment: if an answer solves your problem you can upvote it or mark it as accepted. That's the best way to thank the user for their efforts in posting an answer, and that's how we do here on GD.SE. Check [ask] and take the [tour] to learn more about how the site works.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that by choosing the artboard, then change the scrolling to Vertical, and adjust to view-port height to whatever fits you best.

I hope I understood your question right.

[image]

Comment: Thank you ...Will use it!!