# Scroll bars (horizonal / vertical) on the Adobe XD window's viewport

Tags: interface-design, user-experience, adobe-xd

I'm using Adobe XD to design UI but unfortunately, it does not currently provide scrollbars to navigate the view of my content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add page scroll on Adobe Xd?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/130809/how-to-add-page-scroll-on-adobe-xd)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to scroll the viewport in Adobe XD:

- Hold down Spacebar and drag with your mouse in the viewport to pan.
- On a trackpad, use two fingers to pan the view (you can also pinch/expand two fingers to zoom).
- On a Windows touchscreen device, you can use two fingers on the screen in the same way.
- Use mousewheel to scroll up/down and Shift-mousewheel to scroll left/right (you can also use Alt-mousewheel to zoom).